# EditText editable, but only if click on icon in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener

I have an custom EditText (for writing simple note), and my problem is even though set the view through **setKeyListener(null)**, when I click on the icon for edit in the ActionBar should appear the virtual keyboard, that does not happen.

When I click on the single element in ListView will open the same Activty for write the Note, with difference that is readonly (setting keyListener(null)):

```
rifTitleNote.setText(listNote.get(position).getTitle());
rifTitleNote.setKeyListener(null);
rifWriteEdit.setText(listNote.get(position).getText());
rifWriteEdit.setKeyListener(null);
```

When I click on icon in the ActionBar for edit, same code **without setKeyListener()**:

```
rifTitleNote.setText(listNote.get(position).getTitle());
rifWriteEdit.setText(listNote.get(position).getText());
```

Why not work?!
How I could solve?

Answer (score 0):

I solved!

It is necessary save the default value through getKeyListener before it set a null:

```
keyListener = rifWriteEdit.getKeyListener();
```